# How do I start Chapter 2 of Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga mobile?

Tags: lego-star-wars

So I am playing LSW (Lego Star Wars) the Complete Saga today. I already completed the whole chapter 1 The Phantom Menace, yet I can’t proceed to chapter 2. I looked everywhere, and still can’t find a solution. Has anybody ever experienced this or know how to fix it?